# Como reescalar el texto de una app android studio

Tags: android-studio

Me gustaria saber como reescalar el texto de una aplicación dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo, debido a que en un movil se me ve correctamente y puedo interactuar con todo, pero si la uso en otro movil con una pantalla más pequeña solo se me ven dos de los 3 text view que tengo puestos.

### Respuesta

Tu problema es que estas usando una medida fija como es px, in, mm o pt en lugar de usar una relativa como dp (Píxel independiente de la densidad) o sp (igual que dp pero teniendo en cuenta la escala que tiene el usuario puesta)

Comment: Tu problema es que estas usando una medida fija como es px, in, mm o pt en lugar de usar una relativa como dp (Píxel independiente de la densidad) o sp (igual que dp pero teniendo en cuenta la escala que tiene el usuario puesta)

Comment: Gracias manuel robles, era justo eso